# To determine if standing broad jump performance is associated with body mass?

Tags: pearson-r, spearman-rho

If the data for body mass is not normal, and the data for standing broad jump is normal. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You can test for correlation with Spearman's rank correlation. Using R notation:

```
cor.test(jump, bmi, method="spearman")
```

You can also try a linear regression. The variables don't have to be normal, as long as the dependent variable (jump) is normal *conditional* on the independent variable (bmi):

```
mod1 <- lm(jump ~ bmi)
```

You can then plot the model to see if the residuals seem to be evenly spread, indicating conditional normality:

```
plot(mod1)
```

I hope this helps!